# Exhausted resultset java sqlexception

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

i've been getting the error exhausted resultset without really knowing what's wrong with what i'm doing, i'm basically trying to stock 3 rows from a database to an array of 3 elements of a class called "Logement" in my uni project which will be later used to fill a number of checkboxes in a javafx ui

```
package accesBD;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

import metier.ConvIntToBool;
import metier.Logement;

public class LogementDAO {
    TypeLogementDAO bd = new TypeLogementDAO();


    public Logement[] findAll() throws SQLException {
        Logement logements[] = null;
        Connection cnx= SConnection.getInstance();
        Logement logement = null;
        try {
            PreparedStatement st= cnx.prepareStatement("select* from logement");
            ResultSet res= st.executeQuery();
            int i =0;
            while (res.next()) {
                logement= new Logement(bd.find(res.getInt(1)), ConvIntToBool.boolToInt(res.getInt(2)) ,ConvIntToBool.boolToInt(res.getInt(3)),ConvIntToBool.boolToInt(res.getInt(4)),ConvIntToBool.boolToInt(res.getInt(5)),ConvIntToBool.boolToInt(res.getInt(6)));
                //System.out.println(res.getRow());
                logements[i]=logement;
                i++;
                }
            st.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return logements;//la collection retournée peut être vide
    }
}
```

[These](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHZSP.png) are the 3 rows that i'm trying to receive from the database

and this is the code for the method find

```
public TypeLogement find(int id){
        Connection cnx =SConnection.getInstance();
        TypeLogement c=null;
        try {PreparedStatement stp1=cnx.prepareStatement("select * from typelogement where id=?");
            stp1.setInt(1, id);
            ResultSet n= stp1.executeQuery();
            while(n.next()){
                c= new TypeLogement(n.getInt(1),n.getString(2),n.getDouble(3));
            }
            cnx.close();

        } catch (SQLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return c;

    }
```

Comment: Please add full exception stacktrace to the question

Comment: If you plan is to get more than one `TypeLogement` back, you need to create a `List<TypeLogement>` and add new `TypeLogement` to that list. Then return the list. Also, I don't see an id column. You also seem to declare an array but never set the size. `Logement logements[] = null;`

Comment: Your code seems to produce N+1 queries, while you could probably do all that with a single query. Also, is `cnx` in `find` the same connection as the one in `findAll`? If so, you closed the connection, which means any derived result sets are also closed (including the one in `findAll`).

Comment: @Ivan you mean the whole text i get as an error? sorry i'm still a beginner.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Thanks the guy below pointed it out too and the exhausted resultset error seems to be gone now that i removed the close(); in the `find` method but now i get a `nullpointerexception` error on this line `logements[i]=logement;`

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the issue is because you close database connection:
You use `Connection cnx= SConnection.getInstance();` to get connection in both `findAll()` and `find()`. And in `find()` you close connection. So the following happens:

1. You open connection in `findAll()`
2. You get outer `ResultSet` and iterate over it
3. In the loop you call `find()`
4. You call `Connection cnx= SConnection.getInstance();` and get inner `ResultSet`
5. You close connection in `find()`. When you close connection it closes all result sets opened in that connection
6. Loop for outer `ResultSet` fails since result set was closed due to closed connection in `find()` method

Instead of closing connection you need to close `ResultSet` in `find()` method.

Comment: Okay, i closed the resultset in the find method and the exhausted resultset error seems to be gone but now i get a nullpointerexception on this line : `logements[i]=logement;`

Comment: Use `List<Logement>` instead of array as array should be initialized with predefined size and that size cannot be changed. You get exception because of `Logement logements[] = null;` you need to init array first

Comment: Okay i did that but now i really don't know how to recover the three `Logement` objects i have in the `List<Logement>`

Comment: And what is the exact issue?

Comment: I just wanna transform the `List<Logement>` into 3 separate `Logement` objects, i don't know how to do that since i'm a beginner and still not quite skilled enough, can you help me?
Edit: As you might have noticed i only have 3 rows in the database, so practically the `List<Logement>` only has 3 objects of Logement, i wanna recover those into 3 separate objects.

Comment: @Amine, `list.get(I)` returns I-th element from the list